# still having trouble New Code trying to make rectangle move across screen

Tags: python

okay what is wrong?

I want a rectangle to move across the screen

I want to change the x coordinates that make that the opposite points of the rectangle
if you have a better way im open to suggestions

I added in the word 'Point' in front of the coordinates that didn't do anything

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Polygon", 500, 500)
    r= Rectangle(Point(10,500),Point(150,450))
    r.draw(win)
    while r.getP1()<=450 is False:
        rectMaker(r)
        time.sleep(1)

def rectMaker(r):
    r.undraw(win)
    r=Rectangle((r.getP1.getY(),r.getP1().getX()+1),(r.getP2.getY,r.getP2().getX()+1))
    r.draw(win)
    return r






main()
```

NEW CODE

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Polygon", 500, 500)
    r= Rectangle(Point(10,500),Point(150,450))
    r.draw(win)
    for i in range (0,345,1):
        r.undraw()
        r= Rectangle(Point(10+i,500),Point(150+i,450))
        r.draw(win)


main()
```

Okay NEW CODE again so sorry I have the full sail boat. I want the line to start at the top of the boat and not at the bottom and the triangle is a little messed up. I thought my coordinates were right but I think they must be wrong.

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Polygon", 500, 500)
    r= Rectangle(Point(10,500),Point(150,450))
    r.draw(win)
    l=Line(Point(70,450),Point(70,400))
    l.draw(win)
    p=Polygon(Point(10,450),Point(130,400),Point(70,300))
    p.draw(win)

    for i in range (0,345,1):
        r.undraw()
        l.undraw()
        p.undraw()
        l=Line(Point(70+i,500),Point(70+i,400))
        r= Rectangle(Point(10+i,500),Point(150+i,450))
        p= Polygon(Point(10+i,450),Point(130+i,400),Point(70+i,300))
        r.draw(win)
        l.draw(win)
        p.draw(win)

main()
```

Comment: You uh, don't read answers to questions you've already posted, do you?

Comment: My apologies. I am new to the website.

Comment: Here is my new code. Now if i want to add more like a triangle moving across screen above the rectangle at the same time would i just write a similar code for the triangle?

Comment: You can add more figures before `for` loop and then you can change its positon in `for` loop. It is better to use `move()` - using `Rectangle()` to move figure you use more memory. If you add to rectangle fill color (`r.setFill('red')`) outline color (`r.setOutline('blue')`) etc. you will have to do it again every time you use `Rectange()`. See my example - I made modyfications.

Comment: By the way: you can use `range(345)` in place of `range(0,345,1)` - it's the same.

Comment: yes thank you, Its so frustrating to switch ways lol even though yours is better. Its a beginner course so I don't think she wants us to use move shes weird about using things like i don't know why. I will ask her tomorrow. Check out my newest attempt let me know if you could fix my coordinates

Comment: by the way: more information about Graphics library http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/graphics.html

Comment: Use `win.getMouse()` after `for` loop to keep window open (look out on indentions) - than you can see your boat and you can correct triangle and line. Try different values for Points and you will find correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now rectangle is moving:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Polygon", 500, 500)
    r = Rectangle(Point(10,500), Point(150,450))
    r.draw(win)
    while r.getP1().getY() > 150: 
        r = rectMaker(win, r)
        time.sleep(1)

def rectMaker(win, r):
    r.undraw() # win
    r = Rectangle( Point(r.getP1().getX(), r.getP1().getY()-10), Point(r.getP2().getX(),r.getP2().getY()-10) )
    r.draw(win)
    return r

main()
```

- you used `win` in two function but it wasn't global variable
- `undraw()` don't need argument
- r.getP1() is Point not single number - you can't compare it with 450
- you used `getP1` and `getY` but should `getP1()`, `getY()`
- you forgot to use `Point` in new `Rectangle`
- you used `Point(Y,X)` but but should `Point(X,Y)`
- seems that `rectMarker` don't use oryginal `r` from `main` but its clone so you forgot to assign result of `rectMaker()` to oryginal `r` (`r = rectMaker(win, r)`)
- etc.

Better version:

```
from graphics import *

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Polygon", 500, 500)
    r = Rectangle(Point(10,500),Point(150,450))
    r.setFill('red')
    r.setOutline('blue')
    r.setWidth(4)

    while r.getP1().getY() > 150:
        r.draw(win)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        r.undraw()
        r.move(0,-10)

    win.getMouse()

main()
```

Comment: thanks I will use this instead of what i just posted

Comment: It's a shame that you gave him the easy answer. If you look at his post history he doesn't seem to get *why* what he's doing is wrong.

Comment: your obviously not seeing all the new code I am posting. I am trying I don't know what you are trying to say.

Comment: @Vikram Saran: beginers don't understand difficult answers. Eeverything is new for them - so they even don't knows what to ask and how to ask.

Comment: Ah @furas, but people, including myself, have given answers pointing in the generally correct direction without giving a fully coded answer. We should be trying to encourage proper thinking, not just solution hunting, no?

Comment: @user3011942 You should only post one question per problem, then as your understanding of that question evolves engage in comment/answer discussion on that question. Also you can edit your questions with further information/feedback as people prompt you.